# Generic arguments for serializable collections

Tags: java, generics, serialization, collections

i have a member like this in a serializable class:

```
private final Map<String, List<T>> categoryMap = Maps.newHashMap();
```

the class has the following type-bounds.

```
<T extends Serializable>
```

I use findbugs to check for mistakes in my code, and it shows me that member as "not (guaranteed to be) serializable".

Comment: A utility functions of the beautiful guava library: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your serializable class contains the following member

```
private final Map<String, List<T>> categoryMap
```

here `T` can be any class `Foo`, which isn't guaranteed to be Serializable and so the warning/suggestion/eye opener

If you are expecting it to be serializable in all the cases than make it

```
List<? extends Serializable>
```

and if you *don't want to seralize that field at all* simply mark `transient`

Comment: Hey, i forgot that i had <T extends Serializable> as type-bounds for the class containing the member. Doesn't that suffice?